# Transform a numpy matrix over a vector field

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I'm trying to add some random distortion to an image, which I want to use to train a machine learning algorithm on in order to learn noise reduction.  Basically I want to specify an array to represent a mapping between input and output cells for this transform_over_vector_field function.

```
def interpolate_coord(tensor, x, y, z):
    if(x < tensor.shape[1] - 1):
        x_right = int(x) + 1
    else: 
        x_right = int(x)
    if(y < tensor.shape[0] - 1):
        y_down = int(y) + 1
    else: 
        y_down = int(y)
    tensor_top_left = tensor[int(y)][int(x)][z]
    tensor_top_right = tensor[int(y)][x_right][z]
    tensor_bottom_left = tensor[y_down][int(x)][z]
    tensor_bottom_right = tensor[y_down][x_right][z]
    tensor_top_interpolated = tensor_top_left * (1 - x + int(x)) + tensor_top_right * (x - int(x))
    tensor_bottom_interpolated = tensor_bottom_left * (1 - x + int(x)) + tensor_bottom_right * (x - int(x))
    return (tensor_top_interpolated * (1 - y + int(y)) + tensor_bottom_interpolated * (y - int(y)))

def transform_over_vector_field(tensor, field):
    output = numpy.empty(tensor.shape)
    for row_index, row in enumerate(field):
        for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
            for layer_index, matrix in enumerate(tensor):
                x_coord = cell[0]
                y_coord = cell[1]
                for z in range(matrix.shape[2]):
                    coordinate_value = interpolate_coord(matrix, x_coord, y_coord, z)
                    output[layer_index][row_index][column_index][z] = coordinate_value
    return output
```

Because I'm going to have to call this function repeatedly during my training loop, I wanted to check if numpy offered any functions to speed this up

Comment: Please provide an MCVE

Comment: Perhaps using something like PyTorch or Tensorflow or Numba to "compile" the function could help? I also think that Kornia (https://github.com/kornia/kornia) might provide some useful functions.

Comment: Note that there are [interpolation functions in scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html). Please use multidimentional numpy arrays rather than inefficient pure-python lists.